# Cross domain Iframe communication

Tags: javascript, iframe

Suppose in `www.site1.com` it has a iframe to `www.site2.com`

`<iframe src="http://www.site2.com" ></iframe>`

Is there is any method to communicate with them?

Comment: Did you not search the site with the title of your post???

Answer (score 1):

Look into the postMessage API.  It'll require some architecture work, but you can use this to emulate CORS support if you need it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: What about browser support.

Comment: TADA!!!  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage#AutoCompatibilityTable